# MongoDB ESR Index Rule - Range Filter and Sorting

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

The following statement regarding range filter and sorting and the way the predicates had to be placed is confusing.

"MongoDB cannot do an index sort on the results of a range filter. Place the range filter after the sort predicate so MongoDB can use a non-blocking index sort."

How can we place a filter after a sort predicate in a mongo query such as below

`db.collectionName.find({}).sort(sortField:1);`

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/tutorial/equality-sort-range-rule/#range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding what the "placement" is referring to.

The ESR guidance is about how to define the index itself, specifically what order the keys should be listed in. It has nothing to do with rearranging anything in the query itself. Indeed you cannot do something like

```
.find({}).sort({sortField:1}).find({rangeCondition:{$gte:1}})
```

Instead your query may look something like this:

```
.find({rangeCondition:{$gte:1}}).sort({sortField:1})
```

And you would therefore create your index as:

```
.createIndex({sortField:1, rangeCondition:1})
```

This is as opposed to creating the index with the fields reversed, e.g. `.createIndex({rangeCondition:1, sortField:1 })`.

Note also that this just provides general guidance that is not appropriate in all situations. If your range predicates are sufficiently selective, then you may achieve better results by having the index lead with that field instead.

Comment: - I see, so the statement specifies how the index keys need to be placed in order to utilize index sorting rather than in memory sorting, but the real time practice is we dont generally place sort key as the preceding or root key of an index.

Comment: I'm not sure that the end of your statement is necessarily a foredrawn conclusion. Certainly in _some_ instances it doesn't make sense to have the index start with the sort field(s) as that necessitates an unbounded scan of the index. But if the range predicates are _not_ selective then such an index could still be (very) beneficial. And although it may not necessarily be the case here, it's pretty typical for there to be some additional equality predicates that would come earlier in the index and help reduce the amount of data scanned. Ultimately it's a tradeoff, ESR is just general guidance

Comment: Agreed, its a tradeoff. I understand the difference on the statements.

Comment: Great. Let me know if there is anything about your question which is still unclear or otherwise not resolved by this answer

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the aggregation framework:

- Use the $sort stage to sort the documents based on the desired field.
- Use the $match stage to apply the filter after sorting.
  Here's an example using the aggregation framework:

```js
db.collectionName.aggregate([
  { $sort: { sortField: 1 } }, // Sort the documents based on sortField
  { $match: { /* Your filter criteria */ } } // Apply the filter after sorting
]);
```

Comment: I agree that you can express an aggregation in this manner, but there is no beneficial reason to do so. The database will automatically try to reorder the stages in an optimal manner which specifically includes moving a `$match` before a `$sort` (noted [here in the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#-sort----match-sequence-optimization)). It's typically best to limit data as soon as you can for performance reasons, which is why the database itself attempts to do that on behalf of the user when it won't change the logical results